# Form inputs with same names + serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

There is a table of inputs that created by a script and may contain any amount of input rows, so there are a lot of input elements with same names. The problem is that the serializeArray() doesn't split up those input rows, so it's impossible to me to work with the rows on PHP side.

```
<form>
  <table>
    Here might be any amount of tr like these
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='about' placeholder='about'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='website' placeholder='website'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='about' placeholder='about'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='website' placeholder='website'/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type='button' id='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
<p>
JSON:
</p>
```

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
  var data = $('form').serializeArray();
  var json = JSON.stringify(data);
  $('p').append(json);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5y4fwLpu/3/

Comment: do you want to create an object per row?

Comment: I just want to interact with each row separately, like: 
`<?
$formData = json_decode($_POST[`formDataJSON`]);
$formData[0]['username']; //first Row username
$formData[1]['username']; //second Row username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the result into chunks and then regroup it in rows.

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();

  processedData = [];
  var i,j,w,temparray,chunk = 3;

  for (i=0,j=data.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    form = data.slice(i,i+chunk);

    var obj = {};
    for(w=0; w < chunk; w++) {

      var name = form[w].name;
      var value = form[w].value;
      obj[name] = value;

    }
    processedData.push(obj);
  }

  var json = JSON.stringify(processedData);

  $('p').append(json);
})
```

The result is something like:

`JSON: [{"username":"User 1","about":"About 1","website":"Web 1"},{"username":"User 2","about":"About 2","website":"Web 2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is use array names in the html like `name='username[]'` and instead of `serializeArray()` use `serialize()`

Then in php you would have arrays in each of `$_POST['username']` , `$_POST['about']` and `$_POST['website']`

You can loop through one of the arrays and use index to get same row value from the other two

JS would then be something like:

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
  var data = $('form').serialize();
  $.post('someFile.php', data).then(res => console.log(res));
})
```

Comment: Thank you!. But I'm sending JSON to PHP and looking for a way to do like this: 
```<?
$formData = json_decode($_POST[`formDataJSON`]);
$formData[0]['username']; //first Row username
$formData[1]['username']; //second Row username```

Comment: Ok ... up to you but is very simple just using `$_POST['username'][0]`  this way

Comment: An alternative is use jQuery `map()` on the `<tr>`s and create your own object on each row